# Unix wrapper to make any binary accept stdin/stdout redirection

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, stdout, stdin

This is a common situation: you want to include command 'foo' as part of a pipeline, but unfortunately command 'foo' only accepts actual filenames for I/O and does not read/write from stdin/stdout.  I know that there's an Unix command which acts as a wrapper for misbehaved commands such as 'foo', but I can't remember its name.  What is it?

Comment: Use a named pipe.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `foo` is using `-i` for its input file and `-o` for its output one, this should convert it to a program suitable for a pipeline:

```
previousCommand | foo -i <(cat) -o >(cat) | nextCommand
```

This is called process substitution and, although not being standard, is available at least with both ksh and bash.

In simple cases like the previous example, the pipeline can be reduced like this:

```
foo -i <(previousCommand) -o >(nextCommand)
```

Comment: By the way, this is a non-standard shell feature. It works in Bash for example, but not in dash nor busybox.

Comment: Thanks.  But I could've sworn there is already a simple command out there that does the same in a portable way.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Lekensteyn thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated. Jon, there is no portable (POSIX) way outside using mkfifo, but the latter breaks the pipeline structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [mkfifo](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156), which can create named pipes which function like files.

Example:

```
mkfifo mypipe
perl mypipe & # awaits input from pipe file
echo "print 55;" > mypipe

ls -l mypipe # should be prefixed with a p denoting the inode is a pipe:
prw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Apr 18 12:10 mypipe
```